# `popen` returning nil when reading within OpenResty

Tags: lua, torch, openresty

I've seen this manifest itself when including packages from torch.  The simplest example is from the "sys" package.  For some reason: https://github.com/torch/sys/blob/master/init.lua#L37-L40 is returning nil when launched through OpenResty which causes an exception.

**app.lua**

```
local sys = require 'sys'
```

Running resty app.lua results in:

```
$ resty app.lua 
/Users/vanpelt/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/sys/init.lua:40: attempt to index local 's' (a nil value)
```

*(sys.execute is being called to set sys.prefix)*

I have no clue why popen is behaving strangely, but thought the nil output case should be handled. Any idea's why child processes are failing in this context?

Answer (score 0):

The problem here lies on the ' ' which on lua it has some interpretation problems which i also had( i forgot the reason whyyou need to use this, sorry).

To solve it try this:

`local sys = require \'sys\'`